# wildcard NFS export with kerberos works in some format but not working in some formats

Tags: linux, linux-networking, centos7, nfs, kerberos

I have been trying to export NFS using following format

```
$ cat /etc/exports
/share server*.example.com(sec=krb5p,rw)
```

This format is working fine and I am able to mount respective directories on respective servers.
However, following format is not working and I'm unable to understand why it's not working.

```
$ cat /etc/exports
/share *.example.com(sec=krb5p,rw)
```

Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: wildcards — Where a * or ? character is used to take into account a grouping of fully qualified domain names or IP addresses or those that match a particular string of letters. However, be careful when using wildcards with fully qualified domain names, as they tend to be more exact than you would expect. For example, the use of *.domain.com as wildcard will allow sales.domain.com to access the exported filesystem, but not bob.sales.domain.com. To match both possibilities, as well as sam.corp.domain.com, you would have to provide *.domain.com *.*.domain.com.